# JavaScript/HTML image change on click

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm currently building a website as part of my IT course, and I'm a bit confused as to why something isn't working. 
I've got it so when the user clicks on the title of a course, text will appear giving more information, but I'd also like an image to change when they click, to make it a bit easier to understand. 
Here is the JavaScript Code:

```
    <script language="javascript">
function changeImage()
{
    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src=="C:\Users\James\Documents\School\College\BTEC Level 3 in Computing\Unit 28 - Web Production - Zoe\Website\images\hiddenTab.jpg") 
     {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src=="C:\Users\James\Documents\School\College\BTEC Level 3 in Computing\Unit 28 - Web Production - Zoe\Website\images\openTab.jpg";
         } 
         else
         {
             document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src=="C:\Users\James\Documents\School\College\BTEC Level 3 in Computing\Unit 28 - Web Production - Zoe\Website\images\hiddenTab.jpg";
        }
    }
  </script>
```

and the relevant bit of HTML:

```
    <img alt="" src="images/hiddenTab.jpg"style="height:22px; width:22px;" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"/></p>
```

Any ideas as to why it isn't working?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:Right, it's now working, except that when I click the image to collapse the text, the image doesn't change back to hiddenTab.jpg.  Any ideas as to why it's doing this?

Comment: Oh please don't have image sources with paths like that! Put the image in the root of your website and reference it from there. I'm willing to bet that's failing the `if` condition as well

Comment: have you looked to see if there are any javascript errors in the web console? Also, any reason you aren't using a webserver to serve the page? Things get wacky when you are opening and serving a local file. Try downloading xampp since i see you are on windows

Comment: I'm building the website in Dreamweaver (it's what we've been told to use). At the moment I don't have access to the FTP server my site is being held on as I'm not on the college's network.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `==` (testing if equal ) and not `=` ( assigning value to variable ) inside the `if` and `else` statements.

P.S.: you should change path source, your solution is not so solid right now

Comment: It's now working, except when I click to collapse the text, the image doesn't change back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you used "==" instead of "=" the first is a boolean condition and the second actually sets it

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML you're using a relative path and in the JS absolute paths.

```
function changeImage()
{
    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src === "images\hiddenTab.jpg") 
     {
         // here you use "=" and not "=="
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "images\openTab.jpg";
     } 
     else
     {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "images\hiddenTab.jpg";
     }
}
```

Comment: Backslashes probably aren’t going to work so well. It would also be bad if any of those started with `a`, `f`, `n`, `r`, `t`, `v`, `b`, `u`, `x`, or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

That will only work on your local computer, even if it is correct.
Absolute path will only work on a computer if that computer has that directory structure and the file there. Relative path will be interpreted by the web server accordingly and will be presented to the end user, together with the document.

Also if you use the full path as a condition, that will fail to occur and you will jump to the else.

When you assign the property value you should use = and when you compare 2 values you should use ==

A nicer version of your code will be:

```
<script language="javascript">
function changeImage()
{
if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src=="images/hiddenTab.jpg") 
     {
     document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src="images/openTab.jpg";
     } 
 else
     {
     document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src="images/hiddenTab.jpg";
     }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

This  `document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src` return full path with your domain name. 
So compairing it with your "images/openTab.png" never returns true

`.getAttribute("src")` return exact value of your `src` attribute value

---

Also you are using == while assigning values. while == is used for comparison and = is used for assigning.

```
 <script language="javascript">
     function changeImage() {
         if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").getAttribute("src") == "images/hiddenTab.png") {
             document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "images/openTab.png";
         }
         else {
             document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "images/hiddenTab.png";
         }
     }
  </script>
```